# Include within Class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, include

I'm using [a library](https://github.com/hyperoslo/facebook-messenger/) like so and it works fine:

```
# app/bot/bot.rb
require 'facebook/messenger'
include Facebook::Messenger

Facebook::Messenger::Profile.set(...) # stuff
Bot.on(:message){|message| ... } # stuff
```

To keep things tidy I decided to keep everything in a class, like so:

```
# app/bot/bot.rb
require 'facebook/messenger'
include Facebook::Messenger

class NeatBot
  def initialize
    setup_bot
    Bot.on(:message){ |msg| receive_message(msg) }
  end

  private
  def setup_bot
    Facebook::Messenger::Profile.set(...) # <-- no longer works
  end

  def receive_message(message)
    # ...
  end
end

# Instantiate bot
NeatBot.new
```

Now it no longer works:

> uninitialized constant Facebook::Messenger::Profile (NameError) in initialize

Many of the classes methods will use `Facebook::Messenger::` methods. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

`include Facebook::Messenger` actually 'load' all methods from this module as class instance method. Constants and classes are included too. So all this method are available in the class instance scope. You have too write something like this:

```
require 'facebook/messenger'

class CleanBot
  include Facebook::Messenger

  def initialize
    setup_bot
    Bot.on(:message){ |msg| receive_message(msg) }
  end

  private
  def setup_bot
    Profile.set(...) # stuff
  end

  def receive_message(message)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Will try that now. Please see the edit I just made -- how come placing the `include` outside the class doesn't allow class methods to access it?

Comment: Doesn't work: `uninitialized constant NeatBot::Profile (NameError)`

Comment: I think this library is doing some very peculiar, not good things when it comes to leveraging `include` so heavily. What Daniel has here should work if the code is written according to normal Ruby expectations.